# Scan error on column index 5 ...cannot convert null to int

Tags: go, pgx

In my data there is no null value, thus I can't explain the *Scan error...*

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)
...
func dispatch[T chkRecord](db *sqlx.DB, table []T, query) error {
    err := db.Select(&table, query)
    if err != nil {
        return err  //Scan error on column index 5...converting NULL to int is unsupported
    }
....
```

Why is that ?
A bit of clarification about the context. The *&table* is not a regular db table,with possible NULLABLE fields, but a view and the *Scan error ...* fires on a calculated field.

Comment: can you post your `table ` struct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in database you have `NULL` value for a particular column but sqlx doesn't know how to assign it to your struct one solution is to use `pointer` types in your table struct .Considering Name is the field in your db which has `NULL` values

```
type table struct{
 ID uint 
 Name *string // make this a pointer to the string 

}
```

If the field Name in your struct is a pointer type, like `*string`, then sqlx will handle `NULL` values from the database by setting the pointer to `nil`.

Comment: Another option is to use sql.NullString as the type for Name: [sql.NullString](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullString)

Comment: I tried both solutions, but neither is working. Changing the field type to pointer the error disappeared in one out of 3 tests, alas in the successful one the result was empty.  Similarly, with the field type changed to *sql.NullInt32* the error disappears but the result is empty,